# Type mismatch error for Worksheet..Can't fix

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting annoying Type mismatch error and can't fix it. Below is the code everything seems OK to me.

```
Dim C_Source As Workbook
Set C_Source = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Text)
'**Referring a cell to get the full path of file to open and the file opened..

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter

tws = ActiveSheet.Name

Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
'**Renaming here to maintain uniformity later..

Set ws1 = Workbooks(C_Source).Worksheets(tws)
'**This line gives Type Mismatch Error, have tried Sheet1 which is the actual name in place of tws here but the same error..
```

Above code gives

> Runtime error 13, Type Mismatch

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does the text in cell B4 include an extension, e.g., .xls, .xlsm, or .xlsb?

Comment: The last line of the code gives the error..

Comment: Yes, the text includes the full path and the extension.. and the file opened properly

Comment: Sorry I missed the comment specifying the error within the code block

Answer (score 4):

You need to change this:

```
Set ws1 = Workbooks(C_Source).Worksheets(tws)
```

to this:

```
Set ws1 = C_Source.Worksheets(tws)
```

`C_Source` is a workbook object variable. The `Workbooks()` argument is expecting a string variable, string literal, or index number.

However, if you *truly* wanted to use the variable's `.Name` property, this would be legal:

```
Set ws1 = Workbooks(C_Source.Name).Worksheets(tws)
```

You had it right with `tws` - although I'd recommend that you explicitly define it's data type with a Dim statement.

Comment: "this would be legal" - legal, but cringe-worthy redundant! ;-)